# Finding two sets that satisfy certain conditions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory

I'm having trouble finding a set (which has to be a subset of the real numbers) that satisfies these conditions.

(∀x ∈ Z, ∃y ∈ S such that x < y) and (∀x ∈ S, ∃y ∈ Z such that x < y) and (S ∩Z = ∅)

And one that satisfies these conditions.

∀x ∈ S, (∃a ∈ $R^+$ such that x + a = 1) and (∃b ∈ $R^+$ such that b − 1 = x)

Given that $R^+$ refers to the positive set of real numbers.

I'm not just looking for an answer, I want to actually understand the logic and thinking behind it.

Comment: To clarify, is $Z$ here intended to be $\Bbb Z$, the integers?  For the first problem, just pick any unbounded to the right set for $S$ that has no integers in it... there are uncountably infinitely many correct choices here.

Comment: For the second part, remembering that $a>0$ and $b>0$, how big can $x$ be?  How small can $x$ be?

Comment: The condiions in the second part are equivalent to $\forall x\in S \;(x<1\land x>-1).$

Answer (score 1):

For the first two sets, consider the set of all even numbers and the set of all odd numbers. Given any even/odd number, there is always an odd/even number that’s greater than that. Also, the two sets don’t intersect.

For the second set, the first condition restricts the set to be $(-\infty, 1)$, and the second condition restricts it to be $(-1, \infty)$. Thus the set we want should be the intersection of the two.

Comment: "*For the first two sets*", my interpretation is that the set $Z$ must always be all of the integers.  Try modifying your example then to use half-integers for the set $S$.